# Security Risk in 3rd Party Controls .NET

Tags: c#, api, user-controls

I am developing some code at my work and I believe in not reinventing the wheel. I found a great 3rd Party control to accomplish what I want in a short time.

What are the risks of using 3rd party controls in intranet web applications? Are there any best practices to safeguard you from malicious code in 3rd Party controls.

Comment: do you trust the corporation that sold it to you? they'll probably be able to provide you with their security policy, although there are limits as to how well you can protect yourself exclusive of armed guards at the physical location of your data center in a country with an amicable laws regarding access. if you reside in an oppressive regime such as China, Iran or the United States, you are out of luck

Comment: if in doubt, aks for the source code. Some, like DevExpress, provide the source code on the more expensive licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be a pain (and quite a bit slower to execute) you could always wrap the suspect control in a separate application domain and not give that domain much in the way of permissions.

If you run the code in a full trust app domain the control *could* do anything the logged on user has permission to do.

Much easier if you could get the source code and inspect that for anything hinky.